# How to include php file in .htaccess?

Tags: php, html, file, .htaccess, include

How to include php file using .htaccess? I google it but i cant find a good tutorial or code.

Here is a php include code :

```
<?php require('footer.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code is Prepend the file

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/dir/path/utilities.php"
```

This code is Append file to bottom of the page

```
php_value auto_append_file "/dir/path/templates/footer.php"
```

I found this answer in http://samweby.blogspot.in/2013/07/prepend-and-append-htaccess-file.html link.

Answer (score 6):

You can try [auto_append_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto_append_file), as follows

```
php_value auto_append_file  "footer.php"
```

That would have the effect of including footer.php after every PHP script, which I think is what you want? There is also [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto_prepend_file), which will include the specified script before each request.